# How do I add a button column to Ag Grid Javascript grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have managed to get the community version of AgGrid (Javascript) to work

However, I cant get a button to work?

```
function drop( id) {
    alert(id);
}

var columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "HELLO", field: "name", sortable: true, filter: true },
    { headerName: 'One', field: 'fieldName',
                cellRenderer : function(params){
                    return '<div><button (click)="this.drop(params.id)">Click</button></div>'
                }
    }

];
```

I need the function to be called when the user clicks on the button

Nothing happens at all?  No errors in the console even?

What am I doing wrong?

Is this functionality disabled for the community edition?

Please note that I need a Javascript solution not Angular or any other language/framework supported by the Ag Grid

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with `cellRenderer`, you should not register the event like `(click)="this.drop(params.id)"`.

Instead, register listener the javascript way. Have a look at below code.

```
colDef.cellRenderer = function(params) {
    var eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="my-css-class"><button class="btn-simple">Push Me</button></span>';
    var eButton = eDiv.querySelectorAll('.btn-simple')[0];

    eButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('button was clicked!!');
    });

    return eDiv;
}
```

> ***Reference: [ag-grid Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)***

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that when I get to the office but how do I get the parameter through? I need the Id of the object in the row

Comment: This worked thanks I expanded it by setting eButton.value to params.value then using this.value in the event